# TWIG how to get the first word of a string?

Tags: symfony, twig

I've got a string and I want to

- **isolate the first word** for styling with `style1` and
- display the rest of the string with `style2` **without the first word**.

Something like that :

```
<span class="style1">{{ string|firstword() }}</span>
<span class="style2">{{ string|restofstring() }}</span>
```

Is it possible ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you could write an extension http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html  that trims the string and looks for the first occurence of space and then substring to that occurance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**I found it !** With [split()](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html) and [attribute()](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) TWIG functions.

```
{% set array = article.titre|split(' ', 2) %}
<span class="style1">{{ attribute(array, 0) }}</span><!-- First word -->
<span class="style2">{{ attribute(array, 1) }}</span><!-- Rest of string -->
```

Thanks to Anjana Silva who give me the begginning of the idea.

Answer (score 24):

I believe you can achieve this by using the split command in Twig. To split you need to identify the separator between two words. Assume your words are separated using a space. Then you can get the first and second words like this.

```
{{ "Monday Tuesday" | split(' ')[0] }}
```

Will return the "Monday"

```
{{ "Monday Tuesday" | split(' ')[1] }}
```

Will return the "Tuesday"

More about split :- http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html

Hope this helps,
Cheers!

Comment: This solution separate all words of my sentence but I want just the first word and all the rest exept the first word.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the array syntax, you might find the [`first`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/first.html) filter to be more idiomatic:

```
{{ "Hello Twig"|split(' ')|first }}
```